# Codeigniter and doctrine join three tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hello there I am trying to join 3 tables in doctrine codeigniter i have successfully join two tables but have problem in joining the third one.

**Here is my codeigniter active record Query. I want to handle this query in doctrine**

```
$query =  $this->db->select('table1.name, table3.date')
        ->from('table1')
        ->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.Uid')
        ->join('table3', 'table3.id = table1.Rid')
        ->where('table1.Uid', $Uid)
        ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

**This is my Doctrine query builder query where i join two tables successfully.**

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('t1, t2')
        ->from('table1', 't1')
        ->join('table2', 't2')
        //   ->join('table3', 't3')
        ->where('t1.Uid = :Uid')
        ->andwhere('t2.Yid = :Yid')
        ->setParameters(array('Uid'=> $Uid, 'Yid' => $user_id))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: In Doctrine the JOIN syntax goes as `>select('t1.name', 't2.name')
    ->from('table1', 't1')
    ->innerJoin('t1', 'table2', 't2', 't2.id = t1.Uid')
    ->innerJoin('t1', 'table3', 't3', 't3.id = t1.Rid')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code, seems like your syntax is not correct.

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('t1.name', 't2.name')
->from('table1', 't1')
->leftJoin('t1', 'table2', 't2', 't2.id = t1.Uid')
->leftJoin('t1', 'table3', 't3', 't3.id = t1.Rid')
->where('t1.Uid = :Uid')
->andwhere('t2.Yid = :Yid')
->setParameters(array('Uid'=> $Uid, 'Yid' => $user_id))
->getQuery()
->getResult()
```

More information about [Constructing a new QueryBuilder object](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: It didn't work can you please convert my codeigniter query to doctrine??